# Reading an XML file then writing to a duplicate version

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmlreader

I am trying to read an XML file, and depending on the value of an element I want to execute some code, and then replace the value with one the code generated and then save the file to a new location.

The way I am currently doing it is very verbose and not accurate and is turning into a large hassle. What I am trying to do is modify the "ClInclude" and "ClCompile" elements. When they are found, I want to execute some code then replace the current values with new ones than save them. I would prefer to use a linq to xml approach instead of my XML reader and Writer approach. Here is a sample of the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{57900E99-A405-49F4-83B2-0254117D041B}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>libprojx</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;projx_EXPORTS;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;LIBprojx_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\..\Win32;..\..\lib;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <BasicRuntimeChecks>Default</BasicRuntimeChecks>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>..\..\..\..\Debug;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>libdirect.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;projx_EXPORTS;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;LIBprojx_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\..\Win32;..\..\lib;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>..\..\..\..\Debug;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>libdirect.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="..\..\lib\projx\conf.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\..\lib\projx\hash.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\..\lib\projx\init.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\..\lib\projx\shmalloc.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\..\lib\projx\shm\fake.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\..\lib\projx\vector.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="dllmain.c" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="..\..\lib\projx\conf.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\..\lib\projx\hash.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\..\lib\projx\shmalloc.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\..\lib\projx\types.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\..\lib\projx\vector.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is what I am currently using to get the job done:

```
string vcName = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
string vcProj = Path.Combine(baseDir, vcName);

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(textBox1.Text))
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.CloseOutput = false;
    string nameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(vcProj, settings))
    {

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:

                   if (reader.Name == "ClInclude")
                    {
                        //execute code here- omitted for example
                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name, nameSpace);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Include", "include/" + filename);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                    }
                    else if (reader.Name == "ClCompile" && reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        //execute code here- omitted for example
                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name, nameSpace);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("Include", "src/" + filename);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                    } 
                   else
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name, nameSpace);
                        writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                    }

                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                    writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                    writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Value);
                    break;
               case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;

                }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ to XML for the purpose, then your code can look like this:

```
var input = @"d:\temp\in.xml";
var output = @"d:\temp\out.xml";

try
{          
    // load original file
    var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(input);
    // don't forget to take the namespace, otherwise LINQ will not find the elements
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
    // finder helper
    Func<string, IEnumerable<XElement>> getElements = elementName => 
        // find all elements of type ItemGroup
        // that contain elements of the given type (here ClInclude or ClCompile)
        xmlDocument.Root.Elements(ns + "ItemGroup").Elements(ns + elementName);
    // find elements: ClInclude
    var clInputs = getElements("ClInclude");
    foreach (var clInput in clInputs)
    {
        // fetch attribute
        var inputAttribute = clInput.Attributes("Include");
        // take first and modify it
        inputAttribute.ElementAt(0).Value = "some new value";
    }
    // find elements: ClCompile
    var clCompiles = getElements("ClCompile");
    foreach (var clCompile in clCompiles)
    {
        // fetch attribute
        var compileAttribute = clCompile.Attributes("Include");
        // take first and modify it
        compileAttribute.ElementAt(0).Value = "some other value";
    }
    // save modified file under new name
    xmlDocument.Save(output);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The modified sections in the new output looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="some other value" />
    <ClCompile Include="some other value" />
    ...
    <ClCompile Include="some other value" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="some new value" />
    ...
    <ClInclude Include="some new value" />
</ItemGroup>
```

More information on LINQ to XML can be found [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: It is alot lighter than my attempts and works perfectly! I really appreciate the help. I hadn't really thought to much about LINQ before this, because of alot of the syntax just seemed messy and out of place. This solution shows that it doesn't have to be. Now I know it's power and what to learn next. Thanks again.

Comment: Im am glad, that the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but why you can't use new STUFF which Microsoft recommend to use? I give you an example. Add

`using System.IO;`
`using System.Xml.Linq;`

Let's say you have a xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Root>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            John
        </Name>
        <Last>
            Smith
        </Last>
        <Email>
            js@gmail.com
        </Email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            Danial
        </Name>
        <Last>
            Black
        </Last>
        <Email>
            db@gmail.com
        </Email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            Marry
        </Name>
        <Last>
            Sweet
        </Last>
        <Email>
            ms@gmail.com
        </Email>
    </Employee>
</Root>
```

And you want to modify Name in each Employee

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\example.xml");

xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Employee")).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            string name = x.Element(XName.Get("Name")).Value;   
            x.Element(XName.Get("Name")).Value = name + " Junior";

        });

xDoc.Save(@"C:\result.xml");
```

And that's all!

Comment: thanks for the answer. I would like to use Linq to XML but I can't seem to get your answer to work. I am going to add an example of the XML file.

Comment: I modified my question to include a sample of the XML I am trying to parse, and also the updated reader and writer code. I want to get rid of the reader writer code and go with your approach. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you just forgot Namespace

This example uses your xml

```
            XElement xElement = XElement.Load(@"C:\target.xml");
            string ns = xElement.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;

            xElement.Descendants(XName.Get("ClCompile", ns)).ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                XAttribute xAttr =  x.Attribute(XName.Get("Include"));

                if (xAttr != null)
                {
                    string name = xAttr.Value;
                    xAttr.Value = name + "?modified";
                }

            });


            xElement.Descendants(XName.Get("ClInclude", ns)).ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                XAttribute xAttr = x.Attribute(XName.Get("Include"));

                if (xAttr != null)
                {
                    string name = xAttr.Value;
                    xAttr.Value = name + "?included";
                }
            });

            xElement.Save(@"C:\result.xml");
```

So I just add a string to the tags which have the Include attribute!